# sql query to format the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Here is my input table. I am trying to format the table as shown in the output below. Could you please help me with the sql query in mssql

```
id    type    code
100    A      k20
100    A      m30
100    B      m30
100    B      m30
101    B      x10
101    B      20
102    A      101
```

Output Table

```
id    A_CODE      B_CODE
100   k20,m30     m30,m30
101   null        x10,20
102   101         null
```

Answer (score 0):

Many examples of PIVOT and String Aggregation, but here is an example of both

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,Item  = [type]+'_CODE'
              ,Value = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +[code] From YourTable Where [id]=A.[id] and [type]=A.[type] For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
         From (Select Distinct [id],[type] from YourTable) A
      ) Src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([A_CODE],[B_CODE])) Pvt
```

Returns

```
ID  A_CODE     B_CODE
100 k20,m30    m30
101 NULL       20,x10
102 101        NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT D.id 
 ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + A_Code 
        FROM (
            SELECT id,code A_Code FROM @Tab WHERE type='A'
            )E
        WHERE E.id=D.id FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') A_Code
 ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + B_Code 
        FROM (
            SELECT id,code B_Code FROM @Tab WHERE type='B'
            )E
        WHERE E.id=D.id FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') B_Code
FROM(
    SELECT id
        ,CASE WHEN type='A' THEN code END A_Code
        ,CASE WHEN type='B' THEN code END B_Code
    FROM @Tab
    )D
GROUP BY D.id
```

**Output:**

```
id  A_Code  B_Code
100 k20,m30 m30,m30
101 NULL    x10,20 
102 101     NULL
```